# Drawing to a nested panel using BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, graphics, drawing

im new to Java so therefore I am trying out some things.

I am playing around with Java layouts, specfically Nested Panels using BorderLayout.

The Problem that I have is that i am unable to draw to the nested panels. I am able to draw to the main panel but not the panels nested within it.

I would be very greatful if you could show me where I am going wrong.

Here is my main code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame{

public GUI()
{
    setSize(600,600);
```

Here is the main panel.

```
    JPanel pan1 = new JPanel();
    pan1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pan1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Panel 1");
    pan1.add(label);
```

Then i create the two nested panels which i add to the main one.

```
    JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
    pan2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    pan2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

    JPanel pan3 = new JPanel();
    pan3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    pan3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
```

Here is where I call the class which draws the shape on the screen.

```
    draw drawingShape = new draw();
```

Here is the problem as i am unable to draw the shape to the nested panel.

```
    pan2.add(drawingShape);
```

However i can draw it to this panel which is the main one.

```
    pan1.add(drawingShape);
```

I am inserted the two panels to the main one.
        pan1.add(pan2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pan1.add(pan3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

```
    getContentPane().add(pan1);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new GUI();
}
}
```

Here is the code for creating the shape which is completley fine:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;



public class draw extends JPanel{

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Image img = createImage();
    g.drawImage(img, 20,20,this);
  }

 private Image createImage(){
   BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   Graphics g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();

  return bufferedImage;
  }

}
```

The code does compile, i appreciate any help.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method, not the paint() method. Also, don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent().

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.

> Here is the code for creating the shape which is completley fine:

I don't see how it can be fine. As far as I can tell it doesn't do anything. First of all don't create the image in the paintComponent() method. This method gets called whenever Swing determines a component needs to be repainted. Secondly, all the code does is create an blank image.

Read the tutorial and post an actual `SSCCE` if you still have problems.